# Is it possible to customize Visual Studio 2017 SSRS rptproj MSBuild files?

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

My company has made extensive investments into a library of custom MSBuild targets files that we use to build our full product. Every project file we have in source control imports at least one custom targets file, which all ultimately end up importing a core targets file that contains the bulk of our general-use targets & properties.

Recently we added a new SSRS project to our solution, and this project (I believe) is the new rptproj format introduced in late 2017--in particular, it declares `ToolsVersion="15.0"` and imports `Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets` from within the VS 2017 install directory.

The problem I'm experiencing is that none of the logical changes I make to the rptproj file appear to do anything; importing our shared targets file doesn't result the execution of any of our targets, such as targets declaring `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"` or even set against the ReportingServices-specific target with `BeforeTargets="ReportBuilderTarget"`.

Furthermore, attempting to set the OutputPath results in exceedingly weird behavior. Declaring an OutputPath such as the following:

```
<OutputPath>$(SharedOutputPath)SSRS\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputPath>
```

...will result after build in the following folder within the project file's directory:

```
C:\workspace\solutionfolder\ReportProject1\$(SharedOutputPath)SSRS\$(MSBuildProjectFile)
```

This is weird because it's not even interpreting the well-known metadata token `$(MSBuildProjectName)` as a property, and emitting both it as well as `$(SharedOutputPath)` as string literals into the OutputPath property.

Furthermore, saving the rptproj file in VS results in a total wipe of all customizations to the file.

Reviewing the `Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets` file, it seems as though it does some extensive gutting of the base `Microsoft.Common.targets` file, but in no way that I can imagine would prevent the basic usage of MSBuild properties or anything.

That's about the the extent of my MSBuild knowledge though so I'm not sure where to take it from here.

Overall it seems like MSBuild support for rptproj files is somewhat half-baked, but am I missing something?

Comment: Would you please share a test sample custom SSRS rptproj and some build steps to us so that we could to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to customize Visual Studio 2017 SSRS rptproj MSBuild files?

As workaround, yon can build the project with MSBuild command line.

As test, I overwrite the default `OutputPath` for SSRS rptproj to:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <FullPath>Debug</FullPath>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputPath>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And add a custom target in the `.rptproj` file:

```
  <Target Name="Test" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="$(OutputPath)"></Message>
  </Target>
```

Then I build the project with MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild "<ProjectPath>.rptproj" /property:Configuration=Debug
```

As result:

[image]

And the build file `build.obj` was generated in the `bin\Debug\Report Project1` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's very interesting. I attempted to build the .rptproj and the .sln at the command line, as you suggest, and both emitted the MSBuild & imported properties correctly in this Test target. Whether or not related, several reports failed to build with error info "error MSB4018: The "ReportBuilderTask" task failed unexpectedly" while this doesn't happen when building the .sln in VS. There seems to be something breaking in Visual Studio that isn't in play when building with standalone MSBulid. If I was missing some installation component, I wouldn't be able to load or build this project, right?

Comment: @bwerks, yes, to build this .rptproj file, you should have to download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: For what it's worth, I have these modules configured at present, copied from Help | About in VS: SQL Server Data Tools, 15.1.61804.210 (Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools); SQL Server Reporting Services, 14.0.1016.268 (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 14.0.1016.268)