# msbuild of rptproj output's a build.obj file

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild

I am using msbuild as part of an azure pipeline (on premise), and it is outputting a file "build.obj".  I don't think it's necessary and I know I could delete it with a step in the yaml file, but I'd like to know what it is and is there a more elegant way of getting rid of it.

The command in the yaml file is pretty basic:

```yaml
  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build myreports Report'
    inputs:
      solution: '**/myreports.rptproj'
      platform: $(buildPlatform)
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      msbuildArguments: >-
        /p:SatelliteResourceLanguages=en
        /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
        /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

I'm pretty sure the msbuildarguments aren't the issue (another project does the same thing but doesn't have any arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a general thing for an MSBuild project to create a "build.obj" file. The "build.obj" file is specific to the .rptproj report project type.

I found this thread - "[What actually occurs when "build"ing a .rptproj project in Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/51e751e2-4528-4a20-8e24-09ad99287e91/what-actually-occurs-when-building-a-rptproj-project-in-visual-studio?forum=sqlreportingservices)" - which says that .rdl files, .rds files, and a build.obj will be created in the project output folder (e.g. bin\debug) and that

> The build.obj file stores the building information about each built item.

Comment: That is consistent with what was said in this answer to a somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942322/234954.  Thanks